# How do I make azure resource manager templates extensions run in specific order?

Tags: azure

I am using two Azure Resource Manager template extensions in my template. One is dependent on the other finishing first. I tried setting up dependencies however, this does not appear to work between extensions. The extensions appear to run asynchronously. Even though I placed extension I want to run first, first in the AzureRM template.

Answer (score 1):

The position in the template won't guarantee the execution sequence. If you want the extension to execute after another resource is available you have to use dependsOn and reference the resource you are waiting for. In this example it is a virtual network but it can be another extension.

```
"dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', variables('virtualNetworkName'))]"
  ],
```

[Azure documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-define-dependencies/)